# Find JSONObject not finding object

Tags: android, json

I am trying to parse the following JSON code, and cant figure it out. I am using the code below. But it cant find the object. the getJsonObject looks for name, so How do I find my object 4106?

My Code:

```
JSONObject structure = Utilities.getJSONFromUrl(url);
JSONObject jobj = structure.getJSONObject("4106");
Log.w("JSON", jobj.toString())
```

My JSON:

```
{
    "id": 356,
    "hassubcategories": true,
    "subcategories": [
        {
            "id": 3808,
            "CategoryName": "Current Products",
            "CategoryImage": null,
            "hassubcategories": true,
            "subcategories": [
                {
                    "id": 4106,
                    "CategoryName": "Architectural",
                    "CategoryImage": "2637",
                    "hassubcategories": true,
                    "subcategories": [
                        {
                            "id": 391,
                            "CategoryName": "Flooring",
                            "CategoryImage": "2745",
                            "hassubcategories": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hint - here's how you'd do it with JavaScript: `structure.subcategories[0].subcategories[0]`

Answer (score 1):

parse current json to get  4106 value as :

```
JSONObject structure = Utilities.getJSONFromUrl(url);

JSONArray arrsubcategories= structure.getJSONArray("subcategories");
for(int i = 0; i < arrsubcategories.length(); i++){
  JSONObject jobj = arrsubcategories.getJSONObject(i);

  JSONArray arrsubcategoriesnew= jobj.getJSONArray("subcategories");
  for(int j = 0; j < arrsubcategoriesnew.length(); j++){
  JSONObject jobjnew = arrsubcategoriesnew.getJSONObject(j);
   // get id here
   String str_id=jobjnew.getString("id");
   String str_CategoryName=jobjnew.getString("CategoryName");
   ....
  Log.w("JSON", str_id)

  JSONArray arrsub_snew= jobjnew.getJSONArray("subcategories");

 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The next step I need to read all values, but first I have to find if a value exists which your code does nicely.If the list significantly larger, and I want to get every single value mapped to class that contains variables for all the relevant JSON fields. Would I use something like a JSONReader?

Comment: @ios85 : no need to use user JSONReader because it's available from latest api's . can u edit question with code what u have tried ?

Comment: I havent started to code that part, just thinking about what I should do. Essentially the JSON will return a bigger structure I didnt want to post the entire thing because its huge (with any number of levels). But First I need to verify a particular category exists then I need to traverse the entire JSON, and then map each Object to a new instance of a class.

Comment: @ios85 : and i think your current json api return dynamic json string because if hassubcategories is true means next subcategories is available if not then stop parsing

Comment: wouldnt that break if I had two Objects on the same level? I think I need a recursive search thats why I was considering a JSONReader

Answer (score 0):

You must iterator the json to get what you want from the json data that you are getting:

1.`JSONArray("subcategories")`

2.get the sub array `JSONArray("subcategories")`

3.and last get object  `array.getJSONObject("4106")`;

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this.

```
JSONObject sub = (JSONObject)structure.getJSONArray("subcategories").get(0);
JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject) sub.getJSONArray("subcategories").get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject structure = Utilities.getJSONFromUrl(url);
JsonObject subcat=struct.getJSONArray("subcategories").getJSONOBJECT(0);
JSONObject innersubcats = subcat.getJSONArray("subcategories").getJSONOBJECT(0);
String id = innersubcats.getstring("id");
log.i("ID OF Inner Subcategories",id);
```